# Error in package creation with npm init in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I just started learning NodeJs from tutorialspoint(TP).

When I tried exactly what they said in [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.htm),

That is , to create a package

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (nodejs) VirdWAitJS
version: (1.0.0) 2.0.1
description: VirdWAitJS is an Open Source JavaScript Library meant for DOM Querying
entry point: (index.js) virdwaitjs.js
test command: hello world
git repository: https://www.github.com/virdwait/virdwaitJs
keywords: virdwait, virdwaitJS, DOM Query, VDJS, VD
author: SAGAR V
license: (ISC) MIT
About to write to C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json:

{
  "name": "VirdWAitJS",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "description": "VirdWAitJS is an Open Source JavaScript Library meant for DOM Querying",
  "main": "virdwaitjs.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^2.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "hello world"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://www.github.com/virdwait/virdwaitJs"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "virdwait",
    "virdwaitJS",
    "DOM",
    "Query",
    "VDJS",
    "VD"
  ],
  "author": "SAGAR V",
  "license": "MIT"
}
Is this ok? (yes)
```

When I press the Enter button, I am getting the following error.

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "init"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>   npm ERR! path C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM
>   npm ERR! errno -4048
>   npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json']
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\package.json' }
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "init"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.2
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
>   npm ERR! Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\npm-debug.log

Comment: You are trying to init a npm package in a system folder (used by node). Try creating your own work folder and NPM init inside it, like C:/Work

Comment: you should do it in a folder in your home directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to create a project inside a system folder
`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` for which you need administrator password.

You can open your cmd as administrator and then you'll be able to `init` your project there.

Answer (score 1):

Similiarly, on other platforms of Unix like Mac, Linux, I need to run the command with 'sudo' - the administration privilege as `sudo npm init -y` to clear out all build errors.